# How to remove DIV tag from webpage in WKWebView in swift 4?

Tags: javascript, ios, swift, wkwebview

I want to remove the header and footer div tags from my webpage when loading it into the WKWebVIew in swift 4.
I have tried the following code. but it was not working..
give me solution for this!

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

   @IBOutlet var webView: WKWebView!

   override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()

      var url: URL?
      url = URL(string: "https://www.walkmate.co.in")
      let request = URLRequest(url: url!)
      webView.load(request)
      let script="function(){ var footer=document.getElementsByClassName('footer-env')[0]; footer.parentNode.removeChild(footer); })())"

      webView.evaluateJavaScript(script) { (result, error) in
         if error != nil {
            print(result)
         }
      }

   }

   override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
      super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
      // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should wait for the site is loaded.

You need the `WKNavigationDelegate` and evaluate your script in

```
func webView(webView: WKWebView!, didFinishNavigation navigation: WKNavigation!) {
   print("Finished navigating to url \(webView.url)");
}
```

Actually your site is not loaded while you want to evaluate your script.

** update **

You need something like this

```
// add the protocol
class ViewController: UIViewController, WKNavigationDelegate {

   @IBOutlet var webView: WKWebView!

   override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()

      var url: URL?
      url = URL(string: "https://www.walkmate.co.in")
      let request = URLRequest(url: url!)

      webView.navigationDelegate = self // set the delegate

      webView.load(request)

   }

   func webView(webView: WKWebView!, didFinishNavigation navigation: WKNavigation!) {
      print("Finished navigating to url \(webView.url)");

      let script="function(){ var footer=document.getElementsByClassName('footer-env')[0]; footer.parentNode.removeChild(footer); })())"

      webView.evaluateJavaScript(script) { (result, error) in
         if error != nil {
            print(result)
         }
      }
   }

   override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
      super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
      // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
   }
}
```

Comment: What is not working? The print in didFinishNavigation gets executed? And you are executing your script in the didFinishNavigation method after the "Finished navigation to url" is printed right?

Comment: I will, but honestly, stack overflow is not a code writing service... check if the code in didFinishNavigation will get executed.

Comment: Thankyou, i have tried this code also....this is also not working...I even won't print "Finished navigating to url \(webView.url)" this line...this is the response on the console                                                                                        2018-02-07 16:38:31.033969+0530 Test[7127:197640] [MC] Lazy loading NSBundle MobileCoreServices.framework
2018-02-07 16:38:31.035541+0530 Test[7127:197640] [MC] Loaded MobileCoreServices.framework

Comment: You can ignore that, this not related to your problem.

Comment: Thankyou ver much! The code you give is working!! thanks a lot! i did a mistake is javascript code...now i corrected it....thankyou!

Comment: <header class="scroll_header_top_area  stick scrolled_not_transparent page_header"> i have this kind of header class in webview and want to remove this how can i achieve this ? @retterdesdialogs

Comment: @HimanshuMoradiya You need to get the element by class and remove it.

Comment: I got "WKErrorDomain Code = 4" Function statements must have a name.